# Gran problema con add_filter en wordpress y woocommerce para modificar las pestañas de producto

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en el cual estoy usando woocommerce y en la vista de los productos necesito crear una clase para distinguir cuando hay tres o cuatro pestañas y asi adaptar el modo responsive del sitio. En mi tema hijo quiero hacer algo como lo siguiente.

```
$numero_pestanas=false;
function pestanas_de_pedido_woo ($tabs) {
   $numero_pestanas=count($tabs);
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'pestanas_de_pedido_woo', 10 );
function my_body_classes( $classes ) {
  $classes[] = $numero_pestanas;
  return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class','my_body_classes' );
```

Estoy acostumbrado a trabajar con PHP "puro" y esto es nuevo para mi, ya se que tal y como planteo el código es imposible por varias razones. Peo no hay alguna opcion? estoy muy perdido en el tema y no se como continuar. (lo quería agregar en el functions.php)

Un cordial saludo y gracias de antemano

PD: sé que se puede hacer con javascript pero prefería hacerlo con php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aplicando [la cadena de filtros](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/apply_filters/) del hook `woocommerce_product_tabs` a un array vacío te devuelve las pestañas definidas para el producto actual ( es como se renderizan en el template [`tabs.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/02cf0dfaed5923513de0c88add597d1560c2cfd2/templates/single-product/tabs/tabs.php) ).

**primer intento**

- contar las tabs desde un filtro del body class y aplicar una clase CSS extra al `<body>`

En el filtro de clases para el `<body>` preguntas si es un "single product page" y agregas la nueva clase con el número al array de clases del body.

```php
<?php

function my_body_classes( $classes ) {
  if ( is_product() ){
    $product_tabs = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', array() );
    $numero_pestanas = count( $product_tabs );
    $classes[] = "pestanias-{$numero_pestanas}";
  }
  return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class','my_body_classes' );
```

En las pruebas realizadas devuelve siempre 1, con lo cual pareciera que las tabs extra ( por default tiene la de comentarios ) se agregan luego de que el tag `body` reciba sus clases ( el theme padre haría `apply_filters( 'body_class', [] )` en el header ).

---

**opción recomendada por woocommerce**

Copiar el archivo `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/tabs/tabs.php` a la carpeta del child-theme como `/child-theme/woocommerce/single-product/tabs/tabs.php` y editar [donde se imprime](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/02cf0dfaed5923513de0c88add597d1560c2cfd2/templates/single-product/tabs/tabs.php#L34) el `<ul>` de las tabs.

```php
$product_tabs = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', array() );

if ( ! empty( $product_tabs ) ) : $numero_pestanas = count( $product_tabs ); ?>

  <div class="woocommerce-tabs wc-tabs-wrapper">
    <ul class="tabs wc-tabs pestanias-<?php echo $numero_pestanas;?>" role="tablist">
```

La "contra" que tiene esto es que si se actualiza el template de woocommerce para las tabs, hay que actualizar el archivo en el child-theme.

---

**opción propuesta**

Para no incluir el archivo `tabs.php` en el child-theme, buscar donde abrir y cerrar un div que contenga el número de tabs como una clase CSS.

Según [este artículo](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/#tab-additional_information) la secuencia de renderizado de las tabs en un product page es:

```
// Tabs, upsells and related products
add_action(
  'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary',
  'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 10 
);
add_action(
  'woocommerce_product_additional_information',
  'wc_display_product_attributes', 10 
);
do_action( 'woocommerce_product_after_tabs' );

add_action( 
  'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 
  'woocommerce_upsell_display', 15 
);
add_action( 
  'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary',
  'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20 
);
```

Es decir que las tabs se renderizan en el action `woocommerce_after_single_product_summary` con prioridad `10` y luego tenemos un action `woocommerce_product_after_tabs` que por el nombre es luego de imprimir las tabs. Viendo [el source de `tabs.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/02cf0dfaed5923513de0c88add597d1560c2cfd2/templates/single-product/tabs/tabs.php#L53) este último action se ejecuta justo antes de cerrar un `div` que sólo se abre cuando hay tabs, así que hay que tener cuidado de no abrir el div si no hay tabs.

```php
function soes116586_my_tabs_count_ABRE(){
  write_log( 'afterSingleSummary' );
  $product_tabs = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', array() );
  $numero_pestanas = count( $product_tabs );
  write_log( $product_tabs );
  // solo si hay 1 o mas
  if ( 1 <= $numero_pestanas ){
    echo "<!-- START {$numero_pestanas} -->" . PHP_EOL;
    echo "<div class=pestanias-{$numero_pestanas}";
  }
}
function soes116586_my_tabs_count_CIERRA(){
  write_log( 'afterTabs' );
  $product_tabs = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', array() );
  $numero_pestanas = count( $product_tabs );
  write_log( $product_tabs );
  // solo si hay 1 o mas
  if ( 1 <= $numero_pestanas ){
    echo "<!-- END {$numero_pestanas} -->" . PHP_EOL;
    echo "</div";
  }
}

/*
// según este action en el template de single product
add_action(
  'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary',
  'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 10
);
//*/
// las tabs van luego de summary con prioridad 10,
// asi que le inyectamos html con prioridad 5
add_action(
  'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary',
  'soes116586_my_tabs_count_ABRE', 5
);
add_action(
  'woocommerce_product_after_tabs',
  'soes116586_my_tabs_count_CIERRA', 10
);
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta. Me muestra un error crítico por culpa de la línea: $product_tabs = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', array() );

Comment: pueden ser varias cosas para probar : la mas simple es la prioridad del filter `body_class`, probá con `add_filter( 'body_class','my_body_classes', 9999 );`, sigue verificar que el snippet esté definido en `functions.php` ( o un include ) en el childtheme ( `wp-cli eval-file` puede necesitar un update del cli ), la otra que se me ocurre es que alguno de los callbacks asociados a `woocommerce_product_tabs` aún no exista o dependa de algo que aún no se define: esos callbacks son los que arman las tabs y `apply_filters` lo que hace es llamarlas en el orden establecido

Comment: para debugear un hook ( ver que callbacks tiene asociado con sus prioridades ) podes probar esta función https://stackoverflow.com/a/26680808/1423096 o el gist https://gist.github.com/helgatheviking/2d9e1208a96978b2154b

Comment: info extra para ver donde meter el filtro de body o buscar una opción por css o mediaquery: las tabs extra se crean por código o por plugin? el template que renderiza las tabs está siendo reemplazado por código o plugin? ( fijate en `/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-status` en la parte templates->Overrides si aparece `tabs.php` )

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function has_attributes() on string in ..../wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php creo que el problema esta en woocommerce_default_product_tabs #0 .....woocommerce_default_product_tabs

Comment: creo que  el problema es que me olvido de algo al llamar woocommerce_product_tabs

Comment: `add_action` y `add_filter` asocian funciones a hooks, `do_action` y `apply_filters` ejecutan esas funciones ( callbacks ) según el orden establecido en el 3er parámetro (default 10), por lo general uno no llama directamente a las funciones por que les faltaría el contexto 1/

Comment: en el ejemplo dado se usa `is_product()` para asegurarnos que al aplicar los filtros estemos en una página de producto y cada callback tenga ese contexto 2/

Comment: y que podria hacer entonces?

Comment: depende lo que quieras hacer y donde, el código provisto cuenta las tabs en la pagina de producto y agrega una clase al body, si lo necesitas en otro lado hay que ver donde

Comment: necesito tal cual eso, pero me da el fatal error

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116586/discussion-between-alo-malbarez-and-anderson985).